# Implement an argwhere function

Tags: code-golf, array, functional-programming

The \$\text{argwhere}\$ function takes a list of values and a predicate/boolean function as arguments and returns a list of indices where the predicate function returns true in the input list. For example,

```
argwhere([1, 2, 3, -5, 5], x -> x > 2)
```

would produce an output of `[2, 4]` because those are the (0-indexed) indices whose values are greater than two.

### Challenge

Implement the \$\text{argwhere}\$ function in your language of choice.

### Format

For the purposes of this challenge, we will deal with lists of integers. You must accept a list of integers and a [black box function](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1324/standard-definitions-of-terms-within-specifications/13706#13706) and return a list of integers in [any reasonable format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods). You may assume the input list will never be empty. Your output may be either 0-indexed or 1-indexed — please specify which.

### Rules

- Builtins are allowed, but please consider adding a less trivial answer so we can see how \$\text{argwhere}\$ might be implemented in your language.
- Explaining your answer(s) is encouraged!
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the code with the fewest bytes (in each language) wins.

###### Why argwhere?

argfoo is a naming convention where you don't want the elements themselves — you want their indices or some other quality. \$\text{argmax}\$, \$\text{argmin}\$, and \$\text{argsort}\$ are examples of this. Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22679684/why-is-argsort-called-argsort). (Also, because my favorite programming language comes with this function and it's called `arg-where`. )

### Test cases

0-indexed

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| ``` [1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4], x -> x == 0 [4, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17], x -> x % 2 == 0 [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], x -> x + 10 > 20 [5, -5, 2, -2, 0], x -> x < 0 [5, 2, 0], x -> x < 0 ``` | ``` [2, 3, 5, 6, 7] [0] [3, 4, 5] [1, 3] [] ``` |

1-indexed

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| ``` [1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4], x -> x == 0 [4, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17], x -> x % 2 == 0 [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], x -> x + 10 > 20 [5, -5, 2, -2, 0], x -> x < 0 [5, 2, 0], x -> x < 0 ``` | ``` [3, 4, 6, 7, 8] [1] [4, 5, 6] [2, 4] [] ``` |

Comment: I don't know how to do black-box functions in Charcoal but normally I would use `FindAll(Map(<array>, <expression>), 1)`.

Comment: husk,1 byte: `W`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there any language that actually has a function called "argwhere"?

Comment: @ThisFieldIsRequired Yep! See https://docs.factorcode.org/content/word-arg-where,sequences.extras.html

Comment: Are we allowed to output the indices in reversed order?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I'm going to say no.

Comment: Any particular reason you use MathJax over Markdown to achieve italics?

Comment: @Adám I suspect it's because the function is a "math" function or one that performs manipulations on mathematical objects.

Comment: @ThisFieldIsRequired If so, it should use upright letters: \$\text{argwhere}\$

Comment: @Adám Fixed, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 45 bytes

```python
lambda l,F:[i for i,e in enumerate(l)if F(e)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPqfZhvzPycxNyklUSFHx80qOlMhLb9IIVMnVSEzTyE1rzQ3tSixJFUjRzMzTcFNI1Uz9n9BUWZeiUaaRrShjpGOARAag0kDHZNYHahJFVYKFQq2tgoGmpr/AQ)

Looks like it won't get much shorter than this.

Explanation: keep all indexes (found by unpacking; the index is the first item of each 2-element tuple in the return value of `enumerate`) for which the function returns `True` for the corresponding element.

Comment: best python solution

Comment: @DialFrost Is it the best one possible, though?

Comment: maybe im trying it out right now

Comment: Why the prerelease version of 3.8?  3.8 itself has been out for a while, and I see nothing in this that doesn't still work in 3.9.9.

Comment: @jwodder I would have preferred to use 3.9, however on TIO the latest version is listed as "3.8 (pre-release)", and it's a lot more convenient to use TIO, so I decided to just use that.

Comment: BTW, if you want to run a newer version of Python online, [Attempt This Online](https://ato.pxeger.com/) is currently on Python 3.10.0.

Answer (score 9):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 28 bytes

```hs
p!v=[i|(i,x)<-zip[0..]v,p x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v0CxzDY6s0YjU6dC00a3KrMg2kBPL7ZMp0ChIvZ/bmJmnm1BUWZeiYqGnaGhpmK0pZ6eoUXsfwA)

### Explanation

To get the indices we `zip` the list with the natural numbers `[0..]`.  Then we use a list comprehension to get only the correct indices.

Comment: `import Data.List;findIndices` happens to be the same length :)

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 24 bytes

```r
function(x,f)which(f(x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jc/RCsIgFMbx@57iuxkonYHaxopl7xIyczcLRjEhenZTaXTjIDgXCv5/eOZwnW@LG@ZBB/uczGO8T8yT5YsbjWOWec6D14ZJgiKIPIf1EKfhPaz@pfzloTXEu8cqZ2@XkCa3LaEjyCjKeJNdQagqqG3mSDjFUHwRlaACso9PcIEqI/EXdZuXqtNihf6MzfL/InwA)

Uses [R](https://www.r-project.org/)'s built-in `which` function, which is pretty-close to `argwhere` except for the manner in which `x` and `f` are supplied...

---

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 26 bytes

```r
function(x,f)seq(!x)[f(x)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jc/RCsIgFMbx@57i62Kg5EBtY8WyF4kuYszqZpEVCdGz21Ea3TgIzoWC/x8eFw7u@Dz1rjfBPobufr4MzAvLb/2VzT3fWeb5PnjTMSWgBWSa5XigqXgLa34xf3kYA/luMdpJnEWkSm0t0AgoEhXdVJMRigJ6mlkJrCmUX0RHKIMs6Am20HmEflHWaakyLpbpN5gs/y/CBw)

Roll-your-own version without any built-in.

Note that many/most [R](https://www.r-project.org/) functions vectorize, and this is assumed here (and indeed applies to all the test-cases).  However, this isn't universal, so if `f` is a non-vectorizing function we'd need [+7 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qfWJRenpFalGr7P600L7kkMz9Po0InTbM4tVBDsUIzujixoCCnEiwU@7/CNlnDUEfBSEfBAIyMYQwgMtG0VkizRZihWV2hYGurYFBrrQCzAmwKF8gQE7BeUx0Fcx0FQ6CJhkCeoTkWE1RVFYxwG2Oho2AJ1GgANcQIZBAWQ7SBShTsFIywGwJ0ha4p2FO6II9h0W@jgFMn8Tr@AwA): `function(x,f)seq(!x)[sapply(x,f)]`.

Comment: A shame `Position` returns only the *first* match

Answer (score 6):

## [Raku](http://raku.org/), 13 bytes

```
{grep :k,|@_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/Or0otUDBKlunxiG@9n9xYqVCmoaWgo2CgY6CjamCrqmCkYKukYKBneZ/AA)

Raku's `grep` filtering built-in can return matching indices instead of matching values if given the adverb `:k`.  This is just an anonymous function that adds `:k` to the arguments it's given and passes them all to `grep`.

Raku's function objects actually have an `assuming` method that returns a new function with some of the arguments to the original function fixed in advance, so this code would more idiomatically be written `&grep.assuming(:k)` or the even terser `&grep.assuming:k`, but that's too long for golf.

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
MT
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCJgWzgsIDksIDEwLCAxMSwgMTIsIDEzXWBFXG7OuzEwKzIwPjsiLCJNVCIsIiIsIiJd)

100% pure ascii. 0-indexed

### Explained

```
MT
M  # Map the function to the list
 T # and return indicies where the result is truthy
```

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 34 bytes

```javascript
a=>f=>a.map((x,i)=>f(x)&&print(i))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hc7RCoIwFAbg@57iJ0h2aIZbioZtl75EdDGCYEEhJuLbr@MqEBKCw9hh/3d2bm5wz0vn2z4dqtCY4Iy9Gut2d9cKMUpP3IuRkqTt/KMXnijUq0aclISWyGLtvxeu/EwCI4ydDoOMarzlek0R5jFfSJQSiqco7lQ5UxvoZVlJHDibfZye7Mxt@QkW@hfyZ2kR902nnWfmiMX0n1R4AQ)

Answer (score 5):

## Java 8, <s>74</s> 73 bytes

```java
f->a->{for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(f.test(a[i]))System.out.println(i);}
```

-1 byte thanks to *@Unmitigated*

0-based. Outputs the indices on separated newlines to STDOUT.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##1ZJdS8MwFIbv9ysOBaGhaWg7x9R@gAjCLkRhl2MXsU1rZpeWJp0bo7@9Zu1EkA109EYCIck57znnecmKbqi9St7bOKdSwhPlYj8CkIoqHsNKR0mteE7SWsSKF4I8Hg/BidhLxRIeU8WCmVAsY1WET2Q9FELWa1YFXKjFMooghrBN7Yja0T4tKlM/Aw8dnweU5Exk6s3nloV4aqZEMalMuuBLhOY7qdiaFLUiZaU1uTA58pvWH@n5y/o11/MfMTYFT2Ct0cy50qnZYgm0yiQ6kAJ0YwCFEAT76G97F3vY0Wvc7Q6@bvwu90RTYybKWsk7MKxv2PuqojtJVNE3NCmyDKAigW0YOgY6X@y5VrqaLnbM@ZXLkOrht3Z0KN7LYkLLMt@ZKSI0jlmpTTvfFHWWwQ8LrjX8BE@x62J3jN3pYA5ceX/04IuuEw7Gd4Nvset0eJ4mHAzPcp3Iu4ivVw4GOMH2RH9jW//kweCCi8CCIaH@Lw5AM2raTw)

**Explanation:**

```java
f->a->{              // Method with Function & integer-array parameters and no return
  for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
                     //  Loop `i` in the range [0,length):
    if(f.test(a[i])) //   If the Function for the `i`'th integer of the array is truthy:
      System.out.println(i);}
                     //    Print index `i` with trailing newline
```

Comment: Using `Predicate<Integer>` instead of `Function<Integer, Boolean>` saves a byte on `test` rather than `apply`.

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 4 bytes

Full program. Prompts for array, then function.

```apl
⍸⎕¨⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO94P@j3h2P@qYeWgEkQAL/FcCggAvI9wr291OPNtRRMNJRMAAjYxgDiExi1bmqDRRsFR71bq0FannUO1ehQkHXDkjY2ioYcGEYZALWb6qjYK6jYAg01RDIMzSHmWKkUIPFJFWgOHbTLHQULIH6DaBmGYHMA5llZKBgAxRW0MZimjZIwk7BCItxQGfpmoJ9qgvyLcRVdljMsFHArpugLgA)

`⍸` where

`⎕` the function

`¨` mapped to

`⎕` the array

Answer (score 4):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 20 bytes

-9 bytes thanks to @Joe Slater. Didn't know that `select` can take a flag.

```
(a,g)->select(g,a,1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc7dCoMwDAXgVzkIg5alYDvFDaYvIl4EURHKKOqFe/qudT@9GOQi4XwJcbzManJ@RO0F0yRVsw526DcxEZOWnp2zT8FQDdwyP7bQZnHI0LO1YiSwlIS2bTXBEPKjLt8mVNER9riyo66RdxEXBykJFUGHRR0mXSV4gkn4SriFOP9QE3mi55CggXnbcFKVxyMqPpPYHT/wH3TSvwA)

---

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 29 bytes

```
(a,g)->[i|i<-[1..#a],g(a[i])]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc7dCoMwDAXgVzk4Bi1LxbqJG6gvUnoRBkpBRpFdONi7d6376cUgFwnnS4jnxanJhxF9EEyTVINxT9cpo8tyx5YmwcZZaQN7Pz8EQw3wi7vdY1ukocCV51mMBJaSYIzRhJpQbXX8NrFOlrCmlRV9j8omfNpIQ2gJOi7qOOk2wz3qjM@ES4yrD60Tz/QQEwyo3zaeVM32iErPZNbhB/4DK8ML)

Comment: This is the abbreviated form of Pari/GP’s select() statement in conjunction with apply(). The long form allows a flag to return only the indices; this answer has a nice trick to accomplish the same thing in the short form.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 35 bytes

```
->a,f{(0..a.size).select{f[a[_1]]}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGiNNulpSVpuhY3lXXtEnXSqjUM9PQS9Yozq1I19YpTc1KTS6rTohOj4w1jY2troUpVChTSoqMNdYx0DIDQGEwa6JjE6ujaVVRXKNjaKhjUxkLULlgAoQE)

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell + [hgl](https://gitlab.com/WheatWizard/haskell-golfing-library), 19 bytes

```
(cx<ixm pM).^m<m gu
```

### Explanation

Here's the same code converted to a more convenient format:

```
f q x =
  cx $ ixM pM $ m (gu q) x
```

To start we have `gu` which takes a boolean and produces `[]` if false and `[()]` if true.

We map `gu q` across the input list, this converts things that pass the test to `[()]` and things that fail to `[]`.

`pM` takes a list and a value and replaces everything in that list with that value.  `ixM` is an index map.  It combines every element with its index using some function.  Here we use `pM` as the function so that our `[()]`s get replaced with `[index]`.

Then `cx` concats everything back together.

You can reorganize things a bit to get:

## 19 bytes

```
cx.^ixm<(pM^.)<m gu
```

Which is equivalent to

```
f q x =
  cx $ ixM (\x y -> pM x $ gu $ q y)
```

But this is also 19 bytes so nothing is saved.

There is also:

## 19 bytes

```
(st.^^fl<fm cr)^.eu
```

This solution uses an entirely different set of tools to solve the problem but is the same length.

This can be translated to the more conventional

```
f q x =
  m st $ fl (q < cr) $ eu x
```

First `eu` pairs every element with its index in the list.  Then `fl (q < cr)` filters using `q` on the second element of each pair.  Finally `m st` gets all the indices from the remaining list.

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

*Edit: -1 byte thanks to Razetime*

```
`fNm
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/qKnx3G47IwNtQ4NHjRs0/yek@eX@//8/2kLHUsfQQMfQUMfQSMfQOBYA)

Razetime already pointed-out in the comments that [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk) has a one-byte built-in for `argwhere`: the `where` or `W` function.

So this is an implementation without `W` or any other function that acts-on or returns indices.

```
`f     # filter (select the elements that satisfy a condition)
  N    # the natural numbers
       # using this list to represent yes/no:
   m   # map 
       # the black-box function provided as (implicit) argument 1
       # across all elements of (implicit) argument 2
```

Comment: `ηfm₁` should work. I'd argue that you can omit the explicit function argument by putting it in a separate line and calling `₁λ>20+10)` with input `[8,9,10,11,12,13]`, but husk really isn't suited for function storage anyway.

Comment: @Razetime - Yes, ```ηfm₁``` works, but I was worried that using any function that acts-on and/or returns a list of indices is blurring the distinction to a built-in...

Comment: @Razetime - And thanks a lot for the clever implicit function argument suggestion.  I agree that this is Ok, and it's much more elegant.

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 18 bytes

```
Position[1>0]@*Map
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY3BCoJAEEDvfoWw4KFG2FkVC1LsAwSjo3hYTGkPulF7G/TXt0UTIpqBubzHvEGaezdIo1pp@8xW@qWM0mONOW@KXSkftnqq0dQszPuiYE0wX1s5zuQRyzIegP8ZQhDA3UbL5RBPE3hU6lvNQDSrS7HDCaSACBgBpovD9shzsf2iAxwB@aIIZ63K6SvlUwJh4nKhK/7HGzgbPVzgF3iTfQM)

Input `[f, list]`. Returns a list of 1-indexed `{index}`s.

Finds the positions of `True`s when the function is mapped onto the list.

---

#### [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 13 bytes

```
Position@_?#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY3BCsIwDEDv@4pBYBczaLuNKbhZP0CY51JkqMMetoL2FvrttWwOREwgl/fIG3v3uI@9M9c@DE3o7Ms4Yyd5OUAWuqeZnCIAn7eDAq1AaJ1JKSkhaBqWYfoZ4iiQxS3my7D0HhM62ZsCFHpxqYy4who5R14gr2cHNpy1Yv1FW9whZ7MiorUo@69UShXmVczlsfgfr@Do7HjGX5D48AY)

Input `[f][list]`. Returns a list of 1-indexed `{index}`s.

Finds the positions of elements that satisfy a predicate - basically a built-in. However, this can possibly include the index of the head of the expression (`{0}`) if the predicate returns `True` when applied to that head (`List`).

Answer (score 3):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), 60 bytes

```
proc a[S,F](s:S,f:F):S=
 for i,x in s:
  if f x:result.add i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY07CsMwEAV7n@KVEizB@VQLglS@gErjQrEtsuB4g2SDbq84gcAUU82s8qr1nXRE6D11g8nsKXJn2bsGUROECmRF5gaQiIjCac77sp3CNEHqPD4Vwdz7M@FCaH9c/3JwGwjfgyl8hDbLeKgucChwDq2tHw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-xp`, 7 bytes

```
bMa@*:1
```

Takes a list and a function that returns 0 (falsey) or 1 (truthy) as command-line arguments. Uses 0-indexing. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgebSSbkWBUuyCpaUlaboWy5N8Ex20rAwhPKjgTcVopWgLa0trQwNrQ0NrQyNrQ-NYJR2l6kRtQwM7I4NauHYA)

#### Explanation

```lisp
b        ; Second argument (the function)
 M       ; Mapped to each element of
  a      ; First argument (the list)
   @*:   ; Find all indices of
      1  ; 1 (truthy)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), 84 bytes

```lisp
(d w(q((L F N)(i L(i(F(h L))(c N(w(t L)F(a 1 N)))(w(t L)F(a N 1)))L
(q((L F)(w L F 0
```

The second line is an anonymous function that implements argwhere; the first line is a helper function. Uses 0-indexing (though it could just as easily be 1-indexing; simply change the number on the second line). [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY6xDsIwEEN3vsKjb0tSKmDq1qnqCmsgEUQqBdoKBD9fjoqhoJMiy37n3JDaZ5P66zgy4MEbWaFELUyomFjyhEqEB9R8cFBd0qOGFTX/jWqhHdtvh8b4VJmRzcUHNGnf@e4pC25B/XGAhYPRyabXYCl4xe5SzJClhjlWsBY2g10J4j22c2KNDayZAKeMqO3P@@DB3UfHvi/gDOhDcNgpqnfO1nOwjUfkordMygmMQJUf0j0WP6j7jcY3)

#### Explanation

The helper function `w`, in addition to `L` (the list) and `F` (the function), gets an extra argument `N` (the current index). Its logic boils down to:

- If `L` is nonempty:

  - If the result of calling `F` on the `h`ead of `L` is truthy, `c`ons `N` to the front of a recursive call to `w` with arguments:

    - `t`ail of `L`
    - `F`
    - `a`dd 1 to `N`
  - Else, just do the recursive call
- Else, return `L` (empty list)

The anonymous function calls `w` with an initial index of 0.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 34 bytes

```javascript
x=>y=>x.flatMap((b,i)=>y(b)?i:[]);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/C1q7S1q5CLy0nscQ3sUBDI0knUxMoppGkaZ9pFR2raf0/OT@vOD8nVS8nP10jTSPaUEfBSEfBAIyMYQwgMonV1KhQsLVTABK2Cgaamv8B)

```js
f = x => y => x.flatMap((b, i) => y(b) ? i : []);

console.log(f([1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4])(x => x == 0))
console.log(f([4, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17])(x => x % 2 == 0))
console.log(f([8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13])(x => x + 10 > 20))
console.log(f([5, -5, 2, -2, 0])(x => x < 0))
console.log(f([5, 2, 0])(x => x < 0))
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 16 bytes

```julia
l/f=findall(f,l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7RCsIwDEXf/Yr7IrTYsrZuTMHuR8SHgRQqochQ2N/XrChWJoSQkHOS3J4URzvnTE3wIabrSCSCIpnvU0wPSgJnq@AUTIn9p@BoL43ADD1w8h5Gys1XagvbKfQKljdY7mxfGVu4tXVQODJn3o5bvMrZ8QgD3K/ER3RXftTLnxV/wor8S@QX)

Boring builtin, just change of order of parameters, let's move on. (The answers are all 1-indexed, by the way.)

#### [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 18 bytes

```julia
l/f=findall(f.(l))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7RCsIwDEXf/Yr7IrTYurZuTMHuR8SHgRQqoYgo7O9rVhQrE0JIyDlJrk@Ko51ypib4ENNlJBJhK0jKfLvH9KAkcLIKTsGU2H0KjvbcCEzQAyfvYaRcfaW2sJ1Cr2B5g@XO9pWxhltae4UDc@btuNmrnA2PMMD9SnxEd@VHPf9Z8UcsyL9EfgE)

This looks very similar, but works differently and shows off Julia's generalized broadcasting feature: `f.(l)` automatically maps `f` over each element of `l`, collects the results into an Array, type-infers that to be as a `BitVector` (a 1-D array of booleans), and passes that on to `findall`. This single argument version of `findall` accepts only arrays of booleans, and returns indices where there are `true` values.

#### [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 21 bytes

```julia
l/f=axes(l)[1][f.(l)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7dCsIwDEbvfYrvRmixdW3dmILdi5Re7MLBpIzhD/Tta1YUKxNCSMg5Sa7PMPY6phSqwfbxcmeBO@3dsKfCp/k2To8wMTgtYARUjsOnoKh9xRAhO0rWQnG@@Up1ZhuBVkDTBk2dbgtjC7O2jgIn4tTbMYtXODsaoYP5leiIbPKPcvmz4M9YkX@J9AI)

Even avoiding `findall` altogether, the answer isn't too much longer!

`axes(l)` returns the indices in each dimension of `l`. Here since `l` is one dimensional, we take `axes(l)[1]` which gives the indices of the list. On that, we use [Logical indexing](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#Logical-indexing): As seen above, `f.(l)` returns an array of booleans. When we use that to index within the list of indices, we get back the indices where the function `f` returns `true`.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 43 bytes

```javascript
x=>y=>x.reduce((a,b,i)=>y(b)?[...a,i]:a,[])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYhBCsIwEAC/kuMurEurnoSNDwk5bNNUIqWRtkr6@hgEYRiGeepHt7Cm135a8hjrJLWIPcQWXuP4DhFAaaCEbcKAd8fMSsnflJzHGvKy5TnynB8wgevJnMl0Py7/aFw9QjFiTZOYDrF@AQ)

0-indexed, takes input in curry format f(array)(function)

Comment: Welcome to the website!

Comment: @thisFieldIsRequired Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
δ.Vƶ0K
```

The input black-box function is a string. 1-based.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3Ba9sGPbDLz//w/RNjJ41LCLK9pCR8FSR8HQAIgNgdgIiI1jAQ) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWVC8f9zW/TCjm0z8P6v8z86WileSSfaUMdIxwAIjcGkgY5JbKyOQrTS4Q6gnAlQ1FTHXMfQUMfQWMfQHCIVom1k8KhhF1DeQsdSx9AALG0EVAGRBsrtBMqZ6uiaAo3WBZqOJg4WiQUA).

**Explanation:**

```python
δ       # Map over the (implicit) second input-list,
        # using the first (implicit) input-string as argument:
 .V     #  Evaluate the string as 05AB1E code
   ƶ    # Multiply each item by its 1-based index
    0K  # Remove all 0s
        # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: I think you need a leading `δ` because you can't assume the function vectorizes correctly

Comment: @ovs You're indeed correct, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 34 bytes

```
a=[1...l.length]b(l)
f(l)=a[a<1/0]
```

\$b(l)\$ is the inputted black box function, which you will need to change for each test case (Desmos doesn't support inputting functions as arguments). \$f(l)\$ is the argwhere function. The output will be 1-indexed.

Further details in the graph links.

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cmv1jhnh15)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dyanvc3doi)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 45 bytes

```python
def f(L,F,t=0):F(L[t])and print(t);f(L,F,t+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZFfa9swFMXf9SkujFKbKsF2kmZLlsIeaiiErZT2yZiiRfIm5kjCuh3Op8@uLDuUvswI68@9v3OObHfC39YszmepGmiSPS857rJ0Uyb7CutUGAmu0wYTTLdj@SZPz/robIfgT56xT1DaDlB51OYXh6M9/IkMNG/mgNoaQAtCymGCVnsEbTwqIcE2sZVIsG/Inu6/7V8fnx6@P8MuVtiPl@fHl7CtahZCxjh9umEAsTYXzikj6YyxhqK02ihyCOnmHqU2oXX/6rHjUMZJ9U4dUMmwI@mjcAmtqLvTjg8Cc@9ajcn19jpNA05d6q9ok0EnnJR00orjTymg38TaIF4tN3WoTxYT@N6Sgk7h48UAsDuFmBB/QhQ4KIfwYKTq77vOdrHuhPe0oPHuYyWT2O7iy0eD9FzlHAoO2TAW04LGsoYtQA@zO3oRmkF86LAqhtYVh1sO65pVy2m/5pCTYE67fF2P7aPGFRSTTtDIiPvM4Qt1ZiNVBLK@2IzcDTXAHRRZ5Eia7FZEk99sNaSfhRuM4Af66yX4QJPNIqIfkf@i9T8)

A function that prints the indices to STDOUT and terminates with an error.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 85 bytes

1-based.

Takes an integer array with a length and a function taking an integer.

```c
m;f(s,l,p)int*s,p();{putchar(91);for(m=l;l--;s++)p(*s)&&printf("%d,",m-l);puts("]");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZLLboMwEEX3fMWIKpFNTIUhNI0c8gVRd11FLBCExhIPi0cVKeLb6dhJ0wgqGT/m3DszFk7drzQdx1LkpGUFU1RWndMyRai4qr5Lz0lDtpyKvG5IGRWicF3RrlZUEaely6VqUJ8Te5Exm5VuQQWaWmLHNhXD@CKrtOizE@zaLpP163lvWagHxYleLhSu0Jy6vqngsvcFDDfqz2kUeQ8czPHCfxas54IV9/b@nyKcK3aGGlwmsiLftcyQWwA65MhjHOkDgLYeY3rlDHwGAQM3ZBAO7B/omRH8bnCsJ7q1wZhgw4CjieOJbyaidwZbDHt3ia9lE0l4awORq@vO6VP04/NwwM3AoHhcKjQlsIk3001w44mw7vcnjsJEhN7lCvtQmFJhuwrvoEL9aZNx6MeS6B8ij0ksIMH3Ymw50QFdV88KZyqsYfwB)

Comment: [84 bytes](https://tio.run/##bZLLboMwEEX3fMWIKpFNTIUhNI0c8gVRd11FLBCExhIPi0cVKeLb6dhJ0wgqGT/m3DszFk7drzQdx1LkpGUFU1RWndMyRai4qr5Lz0lDtpyKvG5IGRWicF1BFXHa1Youl6pBeU7sRcZsVroFFehpiR3bVAzji6zSos9OsGu7TNav571loR4UJ3q5ULhCc@r6poLL3hcw3Kg/p1HkPXAwxwv/WbCeC1bc2/t/inCu2BlqcJnIinzXMkNuAeiQI49xpA8A2nqM6ZUz8BkEDNyQQTiwf6BnRvC7wbGe6NYGY4INA44mjie@mYjeGWwx7N0lvpZNJOGtDUSurjunT9GPz8MBNwOD4nGp0JTAJt5MN8GNJ8K63584ChMRepcr7ENhSoXtKryDCvWnTcah30qif4g8JrGABJ@KseVEB3RdPSucqbCG8Qc "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), 48 bytes

```
(load library
(d A(q((L F)(all-indices(map F L)1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7BCsIwEETv/Yo57h6EJFqqp9KLp36A12iCBNKoTRHqz8e1B7W7sAw7b2CmkOYY8r0UijfrEMN5tONckUNHD6IeRyYb4yYkFy4@02DvOKJnXagDSXSChoGS3S5XYcd4@fHWcvVFdmLWaKA19Ba6YfinT//EHgdotQBGGJa3Hc7Ogk4f7XNuYRTIOmdwEpRlfvEalPwVNUuXRRmGYoiyU3j6doWatVXe)

The `library` unsurprisingly contains some rather useful functions for golfing; not sure if this should be scored as `tinylisp + library`. Takes the test harness from [DLosc's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241431/67312).

Answer (score 2):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 85 bytes

```go
func(f func(int)bool,L[]int)(A[]int){for i,e:=range L{if f(e){A=append(A,i)}}
return}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hZLRSsMwGIXBO_sUPwMhZam03cqmWKH3u_DGK_EibmkNrmkN7RyUPok3RfCh5tP4J2lBsVQIJKHfOefPoe8fWdGd5iXbvrCMQ86EdEReFqqCS5ileTVznANTwFT29swVh_izrlJvfbpPa7klKZhNyMp9Koo93Tw86jNJ7N6khQJB-XWsmET7TSNQQbjbJDErSy53JKHCbVtH8apWsrXmX2fnOjOrQohtwBGGiMaScIRbCFszG3_1p7g4Bt-CO3GYdLyA8AeN8ZO-cwh8PUSPS55N0Tfa1tGfTcnEhca5U8jtJRnKJRhJTXNNQCGksKDgRRSi1nX_wvjsX7Bv1mI44FqO6nQLvXBpeExYUQjQJcBbsBpV6TZ61ZrCFXJ-rwm1blSDlfSSyD4EUU9P-j89UP0f0XV2_wY)

## [Go](https://go.dev), generic, 90 bytes

```go
func g[T any](f func(T)bool,L[]T)(A[]int){for i,e:=range L{if f(e){A=append(A,i)}}
return}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hZLBSsQwEIbx2qcYFoQEU2m7W3YVK_S-Bw89WXqIu2kJbtMa2mWl9Em8LIJP4ZPouwhO2i6olAoDk8D3_5P5yctrVhzfS7555JmAnEtlybwsdAWXMEvzavZWV6m9-rhPa7WBLI6Aq-eEpGDuJKIPRbFj6ziJKAnjRKqKNmmhQTJxHWiu0HPdSKSJoE0Y8LIUaktCJmnbWlpUtVZtP-Hz7GvPNWSVB0FvfgBjZwY0PQkHuAWvtQwnnpwpLgjA6cGt3E86noP3g8bxk74X4DrmEQOuRDZF3xhbq0vOJEsoNNadRm6nSBZjTwgOZF1ujcvAYzBnYPsM_JbSvyiu_At1upqfDliLEZXZf5AtOhrdlwxc9HDx5i5HNCaFQbNicIWUMyg8oxpRYBCDwO8XQNA2b_yPPTHDLzge-_4N)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 31 bytes

```ruby
->a,f{a.zip(0..){f[_1]&&p(_2)}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGiNNulpSVpuhb7de0SddKqE_WqMgs0DPT0NKvTouMNY9XUCjTijTRrayGqbmqmRUcb6igY6SgY6yjomuoomMYCabuK6go7o9pYBWUFWzuFaKCsSSxEw4IFEBoA)

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>12</s> <s>10</s> <s>9</s> 6 bytes

```
{&x'y}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6pWq1CvrOXiSos2srE2VDBSMFYwUTCNBfIN7cB8XSAyVtAFCxnYgoUMgNAYTBoomMQCACIADpE=)

*Down 3 bytes thanks to Steffan*

Takes `x` as black box function and `y` as list of integers.

Explanation:

```
{&x'y}  Main function.
  x'y   Apply each value y to x (x(y)), return a binary list
 &      Get all the truthy indices
```

Comment: You can remove both `@`s.

Comment: This doesn't seem to produce correct output though.

Comment: I get 6 bytes: `{&x'y}` that produces correct output.

Comment: @Steffan Oh you are right. I read the challenge wrong, and thought that I need to return the values, not the indices.

Comment: you should probably do `x'y` instead of `x y` since the function isn't guaranteed to vectorize. like i said though, `&x'y` does exactly this task

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 2 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Black box function is pre-assigned to variable V.

```
ðV
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&header=Clh7WD4y&code=8FY&input=WzEsIDIsIDMsIC01LCA1XQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$2\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 1.646 bytes

```
TM
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJUTSc+KzEweDIwIiwiWzgsOSwxMCwxMSwxMiwxM10iXQ==)

The `'>+10x20` bit in the link is the function \$f(x) = x + 10 > 20\$.

```
TM # Takes a function and a list in any order
 M # Map the list by the function
T  # Return the truthy indexes of the resulting list
```

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>13</s> 11 bytes

*2 bytes saved thanks to [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)'s approach of using `I.`*

```
1 :'I.u"+y'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jdBRC4IwFAXg9/2KQxAWTtmWw5L0oSAIoodeQyJCil6CIDLov9uZWGZPwRw6d757ueeqF3r76/F@Kq4F0gQeJBQSPkGI@Wa1qDQSbxneev7Dq4ZClO5WLsR6FmKrJQzv12v0fuGKcokSQcYtTaFEcThdMFBIUQ7xKadhWEdhVO8KUaNGNWYlYgnNEppfOm7JPnM/rMGzQ0dELWLGmWa4kccSE1qqcY2zW9fnH2Qwb9goTN2R36HHmLhDJxvGG5ndBraeRuAm0qLTrz6zDmSxs2x8xyG0yP9hxqoX) Assumes the given predicate is a true boolean predicate, which yields `1` for truthy and `0` for falsey, as is standard in J.

I don't think there's a tacit way to make an adjective as complex as this. Technically, as per [standard IO](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/13707#13707), we can have <s>8</s> bytes by assuming the function is stored in a predefined variable `u`:

```
[:I.u"+
```

### Explanation

Approach c/o Razetime:

```
I.u"+y
  u      the given boolean function
   "+    applied at each cell of
     y   y, the input list
I.       obtain indices where truthy
```

Old approach:

```
u"0#i.@#
    i.     the indices from 0 to
      @#   the length of the input, right-exclusive
   #       and keeping only the elements corresponding to
u          the given boolean function
 "0        applied to each cell of the input
```

Comment: `1 :'I.u"0 y'` is 12

Comment: @Razetime Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

## [tinylisp 2](https://github.com/dloscutoff/tinylisp2), <s>33</s> 29 bytes

```lisp
(\(L F)(f(. F(p nth L))(r(# L
```

Try it at [Replit](https://replit.com/@dloscutoff/tinylisp2). Example session:

```lisp
tl2> (\(L F)(f(. F(p nth L))(r(# L
(() (L F) (f (. F (p nth L)) (r (# L))))
tl2> (def argwhere _)
argwhere
tl2> (argwhere (list 1 2 3 -5 5) (partial < 2))
(2 4)
```

#### Explanation

```lisp
(\(L F)(f(. F(p nth L))(r(# L))))
(\                              ) ; Lambda function
  (L F)                           ; that takes a list L and a function F:
       (f                      )  ;  Filter
                       (r(# L))   ;  range(length(L)), the indices of L
         (.           )           ;  by the composition of
            F                     ;  F with
             (p nth L)            ;  a partial application of nth to L
```

That is, for each index, get the element of L at that index and call F on it. If it's truthy, keep that index, otherwise discard it.

Answer (score 1):

## [Fortran](https://fortran-lang.org/en/), 180 bytes

Since there are anonymous functions for other languages allowed, I assume that I can name my argwhere function with a letter and make use of the implicit typing.

```fortran
function J(v,n,f)
integer v(*)
interface
logical function g(m)
end function
end interface
procedure(g) f
allocatable J(:)
J = pack([(i,i=1,n)],mask=[(f(v(i)),i=1,n)])
end function
```

An ungolfed version looks like this.

````fortran
program test_argwhere
    implicit none
    abstract interface
        logical pure function predicate_t(n)
            integer, intent(in) :: n
        end function
    end interface


    write(*, *) argwhere([1, 3, 4, 8, 5], is_even)

contains

    pure function argwhere(vals, predicate) result(res)
        integer, intent(in) :: vals(:)
        procedure(predicate_t) :: predicate
        integer, allocatable :: res(:)
        integer :: i
        res = pack([(i, i = 1, size(vals))], mask=[(predicate(vals(i)), i = 1, size(vals))])
    end function

    logical pure function is_even(n)
        integer, intent(in) :: n
        is_even = mod(n, 2) == 0
    end function

end program
```
````

Answer (score 1):

## Kotlin, <strike>72</strike> 61 bytes

```
fun <T> List<T>.f(p:(T)->Boolean)=indices.filter{p(this[it])}
```

0-based solution.

Uses built-in [`indices`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/indices.html) to perform a filter on.

Example:

```
fun main() {
    println(listOf(1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4).f { it == 0 })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## F#, 79 bytes

```
let x a p = a|>Seq.mapi(fun i a -> i,a)|>Seq.filter(fun(_,a)->p a)|>Seq.map fst
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Can you save any bytes by removing spaces?

Comment: I mean, yeah, but it hurts my head :)

Answer (score 1):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 31 bytes

Based on [Cool guy's Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241366/11261) and the same length as [my Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252678/11261) but vastly less readable! J-uby still hasn't "clicked" for me so I'm sure some J-uby experts could golf this a lot more.

```ruby
->a,f{:select+(:[]&a|f)^(+a).*}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBojTbpaUlaboW-3XtEnXSqq2KU3NSk0u0NayiY9USa9I04zS0EzX1tGohqm5qFyikRUcb6igY6SgY6yjomuoomMYCabuK6go7o9pYBWUFWzuFaKCsSSxEy4IFEBoA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 37 bytes

```arturo
$[a,f][select 1..size a'n->f a\[n-1]]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?iPF2tB)

1-indexed.

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 3 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
⊚^1
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=QXJnV2hlcmUhIOKGkCDiippeMQoKQXJnV2hlcmUhKD0wKSBbMSAyIDAgMCAzIDAgMCAwIDRdCkFyZ1doZXJlISg9MOKXvzIpIFs0IDMgNSA3IDExIDEzIDE3XQpBcmdXaGVyZSEoPjIwKzEwKSBbOCA5IDEwIDExIDEyIDEzXQpBcmdXaGVyZSEoPDApIFs1IMKvNSAyIMKvMiAwXQpBcmdXaGVyZSEoPDApIFs1IDIgMF0K)

```
⊚^1
 ^1  # call the function
⊚    # where is the result equal to one?
```