# Tips for golfing in J-uby

Tags: code-golf, tips

J-uby is the [Language of the Month for June 2022](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24817/language-of-the-month-for-june-2022-j-uby), so I'm looking for tips for golfing in it. As usual, please post one tip per answer, and avoid general tips such as "remove whitespace" or "avoid comments".

Comment: Anybody have any tips on porting [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241366/11261) to J-uby? It looks like it ought to be simple but has me stumped.

Answer (score 2):

## `join` to `*`

Say we have an array:

```
a=[1,2]
```

To join it with commas:

```
a.join','
```

However this seems too long, let's replace it with `*`:

```
a*','
```

Or even better:

```
a*?,
```

Comment: I don't know if maybe it's not idiomatic in J-uby, but you can omit the `.` for `a*','` (or `a*?,`). This works [in vanilla Ruby](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Array.html#method-i-2A) too.

Answer (score 2):

## `reduce` to `/`

Let's say we have an array of:

```
a=[1,2]
```

If we want to find the sum:

```
a.reduce:+
```

Golfed:

```
:+/a
```

Just swap the `a` and `:+` before placing a `/` smack in the middle!

Answer (score 2):

## Conversions

```
number.abs    #To abs value
number.|

Object.to_i    #To integer
Z[Object]

Object.to_f    #To float
Q[Object]

Object.to_s    #To string
S[Object]

Object.to_a    #To array
A[Object]

Hash[Object]    #To hash
H[Object]
```

All these make sure of single letters for conversions.

Answer (score 0):

## Flip your comparisons

`x < 1` in tacit J-uby is `~:<&1` but the equivalent `1 > x` is a byte shorter: `:>&1`.